# How to make recording audio react-native to server?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

how to make record into server like firebase in react native?
User tap in the start botton, audio start record, when he tap in the same button, recroding will stoped and sended to server

Comment: For this you need to firstly install audio recorder npm in project and then getting uri path(`${this.dirs.CacheDir}/dumy.mp3`) after recording audio and send it to firebase storage which provided you mp3 URL. Npm for audio recoder link is below.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-audio-recorder-player